# How to upload a local json file using Blazor

Tags: file, input, blazor

I am trying to select a local `json` file and load it in my blazor client component.

```
 <input type="file" onchange="LoadFile" accept="application/json;.json" class="btn btn-primary" />
protected async Task LoadFile(UIChangeEventArgs args)
        {
            string data = args.Value as string;
        }
```

**P,S** I do not understand , do i need to keep track both the name of the file and the content when retrieving it ?

Comment: I do not understand what the problem is that you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're trying to read the contents of a JSON file on the client (Blazor), right? Why not on the server !?

Anyhow, args.Value can only furnish you with the name of the file. In order to read the contents of the file, you can use the FileReader API (See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader). That means that you should use JSIntrop to communicate with the FileReader API. But before you start, I'd suggest you try to find out if this API have been implemented by the community (something like the localStorage, etc.). You may also need to deserialize the read contents into something meaningful such as a C# object.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool that can help, but it currently doesn't support the 3.0 preview. https://github.com/jburman/W8lessLabs.Blazor.LocalFiles

(no affiliation with the developer)

Answer (score 0):

The input control will give you the location of the file as a full path along with the name of the file. Then you still have to retrieve the file and download it to the server.

Late response but with 3.1 there is an additional AspNetCore.Components module you can download via NuGet to get access to HttpClient extensions. These make it simple:

```
// fetch mock data for now
var results = await _http.GetJsonAsync<WellDetail[]>("sample-data/well.json");
```

You could inject the location of the file from your input control in place of the "sample-data/well.json" string.

Something like:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

private async Task<List<MyData>> LoadFile(string filePath)
{
  HttpClient _http;

  // fetch data 
  // convert file data to MyData object
  var results = await _http.GetJsonAsync<MyData[]>(filePath);

  return results.ToList();
}
```